# display current json object js

Tags: json, vue.js, single-page-application

I am doing e-commerce bookstore vuejs single-page-application website.

I need to display particular (current) data (like title, cover etc.) from specific book in json when I choose it.

```
{
"books": [
    {
        "title": "The Godfather",
        "cover": "",
        "author": "Mario Putzo",
        "ratting": "95%",
        "price": "30",
        "published": "March 10, 1969",
        "description": ""
    },
    {
        "title": "The Sicilian",
        "cover": "",
        "author": "Mario Putzo",
        "ratting": "98%",
        "price": "25",
        "published": "November 1984",
        "description": ""
    },
```

I tryed :

```
<div>
    <p>Author: {{currentBook.author}}</p>
    <p>Title: {{currentBook.title}}</p>
    <p>Published {{}}</p>
</div>

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
    /// return {
            page: 'home',
            url: "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5c6d3bf80177dd1751730298",
            books: [],
            currentBook: {},
        }
    }

    bookSelect(string, object) {
        this.page = string;
        this.currentBook = object;
        this.currentBook = this.books.find(obj => obj.title === object.book);
        this.currentBook = this.books.find(obj => obj.author === book);
        this.currentBook = this.books.find(obj => obj.published === book);
        this.currentBook = this.books.find(obj => obj.description === book);
    }
});
```

Comment: From where you are invoking `bookSelect(...)` method? also could you share api-calling & `v-bind` etc. codes?

Comment: what is your question? You should probably go to https://vuejs.org/ and learn the ropes

Answer (score 0):

`data` needs to be a function and not an object. Change `data` to a function:

```
data() {
    /// return {
            page: 'home',
            url: "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5c6d3bf80177dd1751730298",
            books: [],
            currentBook: {},
        }
    }
```